# Regex grouping issue

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need a regex to grouping my strings, but I can't grouping properly.

String must be start "foo/", after end with "login" or "something" + "/" + (set|get).

```
    ^foo\/(login$|(.*)\/(set|get))
```

"login" or "something" must be group 1
"set" or "get"  must be group 2, if exist.

```
Test strings:
foo/
foo/login   -match
foo/login/get
foo/sadas/set   -match
foo/sadasf/asd
foo/blabla/get   -match
```

The grouping should be in the following format.

```
             Group1          Group2
foo      /   login
foo      /   sadasas     /    set
foo      /   blabla      /    get
```

Comment: It is not quite clear, try [`^foo\/(login$|[^\/]*(?:\/([sg]et))?)`](https://regex101.com/r/WlQGs9/1). Or [`^foo\/(login$|[^\/]+(?:\/([sg]et))?)$`](https://regex101.com/r/WlQGs9/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
^foo\/(?(?=login)(login)|(.*?)(set|get))$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qAnc4v/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the line
- `foo\/` - matches `foo/` literally
- `(?(?=login)(login)|(.*?)(set|get))` - If the current position is followed by `login`, match `login` and capture it as group 2, else match 0+ occurrences of any character(captured in group 1) followed by either `set` or `get`(captured in group 3)
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

**Updated solution**

```
^foo\/(login$|(?!login).*?(?=[gs]et))([gs]et)?$
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qAnc4v/4)

**Just realised that this is very close to Wiktor's Comment**

Comment: Its ok, but in "foo/sadas/set"; "sadas" in Group 2, "set" in Group 3. Is there a way start with group1?

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now, group 1 is "sadas/set", its must be only sadas.